# pydev breakpoint when variable changes

Tags: pydev

I have Python code that looks like this:

```
Class X:
    def Y()
        return None

obj == X()

def Z
    obj.Y()
```

The variable `obj` is being set to `None` by some component and I want a breakpoint that will take effect when the value of `Obj` changes so I can determine what component was involved. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is use @property on the setter for the variable and then trap within that setter.
Search on @property

Comment: the variable is a module-level variable so `@property` will not be appropriate